# Prove the circles are tangent

Tags: geometry

> Let $ABC$ a triangle and $\mathcal{C}$ its incircle. We know $MN$ is
>   tangent to $\mathcal{C}$ and parallel to $BC$. Prove the circles of
>   diameter $[MB]$ and $[NC]$ respectively are tangent.

[image]

Because $\mathcal{C}$ is the excircle of the trapezoid $MBCN$ then $MN + BC = MB + NC$. That's pretty much all I can get. I only need a hint to get further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hint:

$O_1O_2$ the middle line of the trapezoid $MBCN$, then
$$O_1O_2=\frac{MN+BC}{2}=\frac{BM+NC}{2}=O_1M+O_2N=R_1+R_2$$

Thus the circles of diameter $[MB]$ and $[NC]$ respectively are tangent.

Comment: Right, meanwhile I saw it myself

Comment: If $O_1O_2=R_1+R_2$ then the circles are tangent!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that we have as well

$$O_1O_2={BC+MN\over 2}$$

Now take $T_1$ and $T_2$ two intersection points of the two circles with diameters $[MB]$ and $[NC]$. One has $O_1T_i=MB/2$ and $O_2T_i=NC/2$. So in the triangle $O_1O_2T_i$ we have

$$O_1T_i+O_2T_i=O_1O_2={MN+BC\over 2}$$

And so $T_i\in [O_1O_2]$ and $T_1=T_2$. We have proven tangency.